# Simplicial enrichment on unbounded algebras over an operad

Tags: reference-request, homotopy-theory, homological-algebra, model-categories, differential-graded-algebras

In his paper ["Homological Algebra of Homotopy Algebras"](https://arxiv.org/abs/q-alg/9702015) V.Hinich introduced a simplicial structure on algebras in unbounded chain complexes over arbitrary $\Sigma$-split operads. Not to get too technical, we can essentially assume that we have algebras in complexes over a ring containing the rationals.

There is, however, a difficulty. That is, this enrichment only really works for finite simplicial sets, i.e., the isomorphism (in Lemma 4.8.3)
$$
\underline{\textrm{Hom}}(A,\Omega(W)\otimes B)\cong \textrm{sSet}(W,\underline{\textrm{Hom}}(A,B))
$$
holds only provided that the simplicial set $W$ is finite. Here $\Omega$ denotes the usual PL-de Rham algebra.

Is there a conceptual obstruction to promoting this structure to a bona fide simplicial enrichment?

Since I am really only interested in the commutative operad, the answer for this case will already be a great help. Also, if there are some other references for the unbounded case, this would also be really great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no obstruction. If $M$ is a simplicial monoidal model category, and $O$ is an operad in $M$, then the category of $O$-algebras is simplicially enriched, tensored, and cotensored. If it's a model category then it's a simplicial model category. For $O = Com$, a reference is page 5 of [my paper on commutative monoids](https://arxiv.org/abs/1403.6759), though this was known long before. For a general operad $O$, this is [already in Spitzweck's thesis](http://hss.ulb.uni-bonn.de/2001/0241/0241.pdf). A published reference is page 4 of [this paper](https://diposit.ub.edu/dspace/bitstream/2445/194385/1/720983.pdf) by Gutierrez et al.

So the next question is: if $M$ is the category of (bounded or unbounded) chain complexes of $R$-modules, with the projective model structure, is $M$ a simplicial model category? And the answer is yes. I learned this while writing a paper with Boris Chorny (see Sec 4.2 of [this](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1805.05378v2.pdf)). It's spelled out in [this paper](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/homology-homotopy-and-applications/volume-9/issue-1/Simplicial-model-category-structures-on-the-category-of-chain-functors/hha/1175791089.full).